# nginx: [emerg] "http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:1

Tags: nginx

I'm new to NGINX and I'm trying to setup minimal working thing. So I trying to run aiohttp mini-app with nginx and supervisor (by [this](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deployment.html) example). But I can't configure Nginx right and getting the following error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:1
```

Here is full default.conf file:

```
http {
  upstream aiohttp {
    # Unix domain servers
    server unix:/tmp/example_1.sock fail_timeout=0;
    server unix:/tmp/example_2.sock fail_timeout=0;
    server unix:/tmp/example_3.sock fail_timeout=0;
    server unix:/tmp/example_4.sock fail_timeout=0;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    server example.com;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_pass http://aiohttp;
    }
  }

}
```

It looks correct. `server` directive is in `http` as it should be. And http is parent directive. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

I am assuming that you have `http` in your /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file which then tells nginx to `include    sites-enabled/*;`

So then you have

```
 http
    http
       server
```

As the http directive should only happen once just remove the http directive from your sites-enabled config file(s)

Comment: You're right, `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` has this line. I removed `http` directive and now getting "server directive is not allowed here" error.

Comment: without your full config I am not really sure. if you want to shared that then I can help more.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I just have no idea how many config files Nginx has at all. It the topic is the full content of `sites-available/default.conf` Which files should  I show you? Only `/etc/nginx/nginx.con` or something else is needed?

Comment: So, actually the problem was in the second 'server' keyword. I used an example from aiohttp docs, and looks like the mistyped with "server example.com" instead of "server_name example.com".

Answer (score 18):

You may insert a part which should be inside `http{}` section into your **nginx.conf** and  in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` leave just `server{}` section.

Answer (score 15):

I've been having similar issue. I needed to include `upstream` directive but I could't touch the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file where the `http` directive is defined. The only thing I could do was to replace `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` (cloud/kubernetes automation stuff...)

The solution is quite simple but since it might not be obvious (wasn't to me), here is how you can write your `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` file if you need to include `upstream` spec. (`upstream` and `server` directives are not enclosed by anything in this file)

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf**

```
upstream api {
    server ...;
}

server {
    listen              80;
    server_name         example.com;
    ...

    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://api;
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So, actually the problem was in the second `server` keyword. I used an example from aiohttp docs, and looks like they mistyped with "server example.com" instead of `server_name example.com`.