# How to log http request body from nginx docker image?

Tags: http, docker, nginx, logging

I'm having a docker image with nginx.

I would like to log incoming requests.

My docker-compose file:

```
nginx:
  container_name: my-nginx
image: nginx
ports:
  - "80:80"
  - "443:443"
volumes:
  - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  - ./access.log:/var/log/nginx/test.com.access.log
```

My nginx config:

```
server {
 listen 80;
 listen 443 default_server ssl;
 access_log /var/log/nginx/test.com.access.log;

 location / {
  proxy_pass http://myapp:8080;
  proxy_buffering off;
 }
}
```

When I try to replace `access_log` directive with following config:

```
log_format testlog '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                   '"$request" $status $bytes_sent '
                   '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$request_body"';
access_log /var/log/nginx/test.com.access.log testlog;
```

I'm getting:

```
nginx-reverse-proxy | 2018/04/06 11:50:00 [emerg] 1#1: "log_format" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:10
nginx-reverse-proxy | nginx: [emerg] "log_format" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:10
```

Comment: You shouldn't have listeners for HTTP and HTTPS in the same server block, but instead create a separate one for HTTPS including the needed SSL keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the log_format outside the `server{}` block, because not every directive can go anywhere. Simply:

```
log_format testlog '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
               '"$request" $status $bytes_sent '
               '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$request_body"';

server {
 listen 80;
 listen 443 default_server ssl;
 access_log /var/log/nginx/test.com.access.log;

 location / {
  proxy_pass http://myapp:8080;
  proxy_buffering off;
 }
}
```

It is docuemnted here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format "Context:  http"

`http` context is the top level block, the one that contains your `server` block (usually you don't see it because it is in another file that is including your .conf)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43643829/nginx-emerg-http-directive-is-not-allowed-here-in-etc-nginx-sites-enabled).

The message means that you have an `http` directive somewhere it's not allowed, i.e.

```
http {
    ...
}
```

You probably want to use a `server` block instead, i.e.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name test.com;
    root /var/www/test/;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/test.com.access.log;
}
```

Comment: But how do I log http body in config you provided?

Comment: If you need to log the request body you can check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7473603/3990318).

Comment: Could you maybe just post your whole nginx config file? Maybe in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/)

Comment: Ok, my file https://gist.github.com/kkocel/5cd206d2bfee9e1ba3d51654c82daacb

Comment: Your provided debug log doesn't match with the gist, please update your question so it does... If I don't have correct debug information I cannot help you that well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168416/discussion-between-pixel-and-niels-de-bruin).