# How to solve "http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:1

Tags: nginx, aiohttp

I follow this [step](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deployment.html) but somehow this throws error..

default config is

```
http {
  upstream alert {
    # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
    # to return a good HTTP response

    # Unix domain servers
    server unix:/tmp/alert_1.sock fail_timeout=0;
    server unix:/tmp/alert_2.sock fail_timeout=0;
    server unix:/tmp/alert_3.sock fail_timeout=0;
    server unix:/tmp/alert_4.sock fail_timeout=0;

    # Unix domain sockets are used in this example due to their high performance,
    # but TCP/IP sockets could be used instead:
    # server 127.0.0.1:8081 fail_timeout=0;
    # server 127.0.0.1:8082 fail_timeout=0;
    # server 127.0.0.1:8083 fail_timeout=0;
    # server 127.0.0.1:8084 fail_timeout=0;
  }
  server {
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    server_name myiphere;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_pass http://alert;
    }

    location /static {
      # path for static files
      root /mylocation/static;
    }

  }
}
```

> nginx: [emerg] "http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:1
>   nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nginx: \[emerg\] "http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43643829/nginx-emerg-http-directive-is-not-allowed-here-in-etc-nginx-sites-enabled)

Answer (score 6):

Check your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. If you are opening `http` directive there, and then opening it again into your `sites-enabled/` folder conf file you will end up with nested `http` directive.

Answer (score 6):

My response is about 9months late, but I have just experienced the same issue.

I decided to add my response because the last 2 answers only hinted at the solution and might still be confusing for some people.

A more straightforward answer is:

Remove the http declaration from your config above, since it most likely has been defined in your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file (You can check that file to verify the claim).

So, your config should eventually look like this:

```
    upstream alert {
        # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
        # to return a good HTTP response
    
        # Unix domain servers
        server unix:/tmp/alert_1.sock fail_timeout=0;
        server unix:/tmp/alert_2.sock fail_timeout=0;
        server unix:/tmp/alert_3.sock fail_timeout=0;
        server unix:/tmp/alert_4.sock fail_timeout=0;
    
        # Unix domain sockets are used in this example due to their high performance,
        # but TCP/IP sockets could be used instead:
        # server 127.0.0.1:8081 fail_timeout=0;
        # server 127.0.0.1:8082 fail_timeout=0;
        # server 127.0.0.1:8083 fail_timeout=0;
        # server 127.0.0.1:8084 fail_timeout=0;
      }
      server {
        listen 80;
        client_max_body_size 4G;
    
        server_name myiphere;
    
        location / {
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_redirect off;
          proxy_buffering off;
          proxy_pass http://alert;
        }
    
        location /static {
          # path for static files
          root /mylocation/static;
        }
    
      }
```

Comment: Still getting an error, `nginx: [emerg] "upstream" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1`

Comment: @SnazzyMohit is it possible your "upstream" directive is nested in-correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Normally nginx.conf (in linux is under /etc/nginx/nginx.conf) contains an inclusion of configuration file within the "http" declaration.

[image: The end of nginx.conf http configuration]

Since it refer to .conf file contained into your conf.d directory (check out the screenshot), you can add a file ending with .conf extension and named as you wish, for example: ASyouWISH.conf.

In my case I added there my websocket configuration without "http" declaration, since it is included into my .conf file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with you met.I set a nginx config not directly in /ect/nginx/nginx.conf but in  http{} in /ect/nginx/nginx.conf.
So you can remove the /ect/nginx/nginx.conf and create a new /ect/nginx/nginx.conf with your own config code.