# Nginx error - problem including server_names_hash_bucket_size to conf.d file

Tags: nginx, server

How do I insert the “server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;” in my conf.d file?

The file I want to build for my specific case is /etc/nginx/conf.d/dev.demo.kmdashboard.dashboardsanddatabases.com.conf.

#### My error

```
Error while running nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t.

nginx: [emerg] could not build server_names_hash, you should increase server_names_hash_bucket_size: 64
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

This occurs after I tried to `sudo certbot --nginx -d dev.demo.kmdashboard.dashboardsanddatabases.com`. Now all my attempts to create my /etc/nginx/conf.d/dev.demo.kmdashboard.dashboardsanddatabases.com.conf file with some version of the `http{server_...}` below are unsuccessful.

```
http {
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
```

## Here is what I have looked at and tried:

#### Documentation

I have looked at the documentation here:
https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#optimization.
I interpreted that there is another http{} section that would include the `server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;`. I’ve tried variations of this to no avail.

#### Other Stack Post that looked promising

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43644053/11925053) seemed most helpful and aligns with other sources. My best attempt to leverage it's suggestion have been unsuccessful.

#### My best attempt

The file is /etc/nginx/conf.d/dev.demo.kmdashboard.dashboardsanddatabases.com.conf

```
http {
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    http {
        server {

            listen       80;
            listen       [::]:80;
            server_name  dev.demo.kmdashboard.dashboardsanddatabases.com;
            client_max_body_size 30G;
            

            location /static {
                alias /home/sanjose/applications/kmdashboard03_dev/app_package/static;
            }

            location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8007;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
                proxy_redirect off;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the typical structure for files in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ when the urls less than 32 characters.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name  nhtsa-dash.kineticmetrics.com demo.kmdashboard.dashboardsanddatabases.com;
    client_max_body_size 30G;

location /static {
    alias /home/sanjose/applications/kmdashboard03/app_package/static;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8006;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
}
```

One odd thing is that this last conf.d file is actually being used currently. You'll notice the second url (demo.kmdashboard.dashboardsanddatabases.com) is longer than 32 characters. Maybe I am misunderstanding what the 32 means? It doesn't mean characters?

Comment: The error seems to relate to the value "64". Have you tried increasing the value to "128"?